# Why is Vim and vi adding leadings characters instead of a blank line?

Tags: vim

On [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra), the *o* command adds a new line leading with a # instead of a blank line as expected.  This is off of a "#include <stdio.h>" line.  Other lines do similar things. How can I revert back to normal Vim (vi does the same thing)?

I checked *:version* and all those rc files do not exist. The issue started after I tried to install an add on to do advanced syntax help.

Comment: Try vi.stackexchange.com, but this is normal behavior when the file type is set to a language that uses `#` to start a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is caused by the presence of `o` in the current value of the `:help 'formatoptions'` option, which doesn't have it by default.

> The issue started after I tried to install an add on to do advanced syntax help.

During that process, you probably added some variant of the following line in your `vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
```

which enables filetype detection and filetype plugins. The latter are filetype-specific plugins that, among other things, may redefine some options for the buffers belonging to that filetype.

In this case, Vim sets the filetype of the buffer to `c` (or maybe `cpp` but I will asume `c` from now on for simplicity), which triggers the sourcing of the corresponding ftplugin, which contains this:

```
" Set 'formatoptions' to break comment lines but not other lines,
" and insert the comment leader when hitting <CR> or using "o".
setlocal fo-=t fo+=croql
```

Note the `o` in `croql`.

If you don't like that, you can either avoid enabling ftplugins by removing `plugin` from the `vimrc` line mentioned above, or write your own ftplugin override:

```
" in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim
setlocal formatoptions=xxxxxxx
```

See `:help fo-table` for the potential values of `formatoptions`.

Comment: THANKS!  I think all the rc files are blank; re-checking now...

Comment: I did "mv /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.bak" and reloaded, which solved the issue.

Comment: No. Toying with system files didn't solve the issue, it only created future ones. Do you have a `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`?